# How do I find the root mean squared error in R?

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to find the root mean squared error on a ksvm model and also plotting the results using the `airquality` dataframe. This is what I have so far:

```
library(kernlab)
library(ggplot2)
AQ <- airquality

set.seed(1)
randIndex <- sample(1:dim(AQ)[1])
cutPoint2_3<- floor(2 * dim(AQ)[1]/3)
cutPoint2_3
TrainAQ <- AQ[randIndex[1:cutPoint2_3],]
TestAQ <- AQ[randIndex[(cutPoint2_3+1) :dim(AQ)[1]],]

svmOutput <- ksvm(Ozone ~., data=TrainAQ, kernel = "rbfdot", 
kpar='automatic',C=5,cross=3, prob.model=TRUE)

#Test the model on the testing dataset, and compute the Root Mean Squared    Error
svmOutputtest <- ksvm(Ozone ~., data=TestAQ, 
                      kernel = "rbfdot",
                      kpar="automatic",
                      C=5,
                      cross=3,
                      prob.model=TRUE)

#root mean squared is ?

#Plot the   results. Use a scatter  plot. Have the  x-axis  represent    temperature, the   y-axis  represent   wind,   the point   size    and color    represent  the error,  as  defined by  the actual  ozone   level minus the  predicted  ozone   level).
ggplot(AQ,aes(x=Temp,y= Wind,color=svmOutput$Error,shape=svmOutput$Error)) +geom_point(size=5)
```

Comment: What is `TrainAQ` and `TestAQ`? Please include the complete code to make your problem reproducible.

Comment: Apologies for the miss. I added those above.

Comment: Shouldn't you use your model to predict `Ozone` values based on the `TestAQ` data? The rmse could then be easily calculated.

Comment: I don't know much about the function `ksvm` but it seems you are fitting two separate models to training and testing data. Look into ways to use the function `predict` with the testing data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Root mean square error in R - mixed effect model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646654/root-mean-square-error-in-r-mixed-effect-model)

Comment: @markus what would be the code to predict and then how would I calculate the rmse then?

Comment: See `help("predict")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of NA's in that TestAQ dataframe so I would remove them first:

```
  TestAQ <- TestAQ[complete.cases(TestAQ), ]
```

Then calculating the Root Mean Squared Error is a simple matter of parsing that verys descripted terminology:

```
 sqrt( mean( TestAQ$Ozone-predict(svmOutputtest,newdata=TestAQ ))^2) 
[1] 2.182599
```

The ggplot call makes no sense since that `svmOutputtest` object is S4 so cannot be accessed and it has no `Error` slot so simple substitution of `@` for `$` will not fix the syntax error. The library is spelled `ggplot2`. Multi-part questions are deprecated on SO, so I'm not going to try to get clarification on that issue.